# How to make Win-Form components created on one PC look the same on other PC's

Tags: size

I have a Windows Form with few buttons and picture box. I'm using specific font for those buttons(Buxton Sketch; 15,75pt; style=Bold, if that makes any sense). That's how it looks on my PC:

[image]

It looks fine on my PC but when I run the .exe file on other PC's, the form is kind of deformed:
[image]

Almost all of the buttons have changed their size and the text don't fit in anymore. What should I do to solve this problem and make those buttons look on other PC's as good as they are looking on mine?

Answer (score 1):

The simple reason behind this anomaly is that, the second PC where you load your application does not support the font to display the button text. Either you include the font also along with your application package or select a font such as Arial, Tahoma, etc... which will be available in most of the Windows PCs.

Comment: I may change the font but will that fix the "text going out of borders of the button" issue?